# Google Analytics: How to get WeChat traffic to show as a social network

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, social-media

One of our clients is doing a lot of advertising on WeChat, the leading social network in China (800M+ active users). As it's an international client, we're using Google Analytics as main platform for their web analytics.

As WeChat traffic is labeled as Direct traffic by default in GA, we decided to tag all URLs shared via WeChat with UTM tags.

For example: www.example.com/?utm_source=wechat&utm_medium=social

That traffic shows up in GA under Acquisition -> Channels -> Social as "(not set)"

[image: social network not set]
[image: not set traffic is from wechat]

While what I want is to have it show up as "WeChat" Social Network under Social traffic (not "(not set)")

I saw some suggestions online to add it in my view's Channel Grouping Settings, but that doesn't help with "(not set)" issue.

[image: channel grouping settings]

Comment: Are you expecting it to backdate? because it won't, it will only show the change in Channel from the time the change was made.

Comment: Not expecting backdate, just to have it apply to future traffic. That works for you?